# how can i make the indicator nadaraya watson envelope output twice with different variables. It should be two upper borders and two lower borders

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

i want to run the nadaraya watson envelope twice but it should run in one indicator. Can someone tell me how to solve it?
so sieht der Quellcode von Nadaraya Watson Indicator

`

```
// This work is licensed under a Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International (CC BY-   NC-SA 4.0) https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/
// © LuxAlgo
//@version=5

indicator("Nadaraya-Watson Envelope [LuxAlgo]",overlay=true,max_bars_back=1000,max_lines_count=500,max_labels_count=500)
length = input.float(500,'Window Size',maxval=500,minval=0)
h      = input.float(8.,'Bandwidth')
mult   = input.float(3.) 
src    = input.source(close,'Source')


up_col = input.color(#39ff14,'Colors',inline='col')
dn_col = input.color(#ff1100,'',inline='col')
disclaimer = input(false, 'Hide Disclaimer')
//----
n = bar_index
var k = 2
var upper = array.new_line(0) 
var lower = array.new_line(0) 

lset(l,x1,y1,x2,y2,col)=>
    line.set_xy1(l,x1,y1)
    line.set_xy2(l,x2,y2)
    line.set_color(l,col)
    line.set_width(l,2)

if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to length/k-1
        array.push(upper,line.new(na,na,na,na))
        array.push(lower,line.new(na,na,na,na))
//----
line up = na
line dn = na
//----
cross_up = 0.
cross_dn = 0.
if barstate.islast
    y = array.new_float(0)
    
    sum_e = 0.
    for i = 0 to length-1
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        
        for j = 0 to length-1
            w = math.exp(-(math.pow(i-j,2)/(h*h*2)))
            sum += src[j]*w
            sumw += w
        
        y2 = sum/sumw
        sum_e += math.abs(src[i] - y2)
        array.push(y,y2)

    mae = sum_e/length*mult
    
    for i = 1 to length-1
        y2 = array.get(y,i)
        y1 = array.get(y,i-1)
        
        up := array.get(upper,i/k)
        dn := array.get(lower,i/k)
        
        lset(up,n-i+1,y1 + mae,n-i,y2 + mae,up_col)
        lset(dn,n-i+1,y1 - mae,n-i,y2 - mae,dn_col)
        
        if src[i] > y1 + mae and src[i+1] < y1 + mae
            label.new(n-i,src[i],'▼',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_down,textcolor=dn_col,textalign=text.align_center)
        if src[i] < y1 - mae and src[i+1] > y1 - mae
            label.new(n-i,src[i],'▲',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_up,textcolor=up_col,textalign=text.align_center)
    
    cross_up := array.get(y,0) + mae
    cross_dn := array.get(y,0) - mae

alertcondition(ta.crossover(src,cross_up),'Down','Down')
alertcondition(ta.crossunder(src,cross_dn),'Up','Up')

//----
var tb = table.new(position.top_right, 1, 1
  , bgcolor = #35202b)

if barstate.isfirst and not disclaimer
    table.cell(tb, 0, 0, 'Nadaraya-Watson Envelope [LUX] Repaints'
      , text_size = size.small
      , text_color = #cc2f3c)
```

`

this is how my result looked
`

```
// © Mikail.Qaed
//@version=5

indicator("Nadaraya-Watson Envelope [LuxAlgo]",overlay=true,max_bars_back=1000,max_lines_count=500,max_labels_count=500)
length = input.float(500,'Window Size',maxval=500,minval=0)
h      = input.float(8.,'Bandwidth')
mult   = input.float(3.) 
src    = input.source(close,'Source')


up_col = input.color(#39ff14,'Colors',inline='col')
dn_col = input.color(#ff1100,'',inline='col')
disclaimer = input(false, 'Hide Disclaimer')
//----
n = bar_index
var k = 2
var upper = array.new_line(0) 
var lower = array.new_line(0) 

lset(l,x1,y1,x2,y2,col)=>
    line.set_xy1(l,x1,y1)
    line.set_xy2(l,x2,y2)
    line.set_color(l,col)
    line.set_width(l,2)

if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to length/k-1
        array.push(upper,line.new(na,na,na,na))
        array.push(lower,line.new(na,na,na,na))
//----
line up = na
line dn = na
//----
cross_up = 0.
cross_dn = 0.
if barstate.islast
    y = array.new_float(0)
    
    sum_e = 0.
    for i = 0 to length-1
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        
        for j = 0 to length-1
            w = math.exp(-(math.pow(i-j,2)/(h*h*2)))
            sum += src[j]*w
            sumw += w
        
        y2 = sum/sumw
        sum_e += math.abs(src[i] - y2)
        array.push(y,y2)

    mae = sum_e/length*mult
    
    for i = 1 to length-1
        y2 = array.get(y,i)
        y1 = array.get(y,i-1)
        
        up := array.get(upper,i/k)
        dn := array.get(lower,i/k)
        
        lset(up,n-i+1,y1 + mae,n-i,y2 + mae,up_col)
        lset(dn,n-i+1,y1 - mae,n-i,y2 - mae,dn_col)
        
        if src[i] > y1 + mae and src[i+1] < y1 + mae
            label.new(n-i,src[i],'▼',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_down,textcolor=dn_col,textalign=text.align_center)
        if src[i] < y1 - mae and src[i+1] > y1 - mae
            label.new(n-i,src[i],'▲',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_up,textcolor=up_col,textalign=text.align_center)
    
    cross_up := array.get(y,0) + mae
    cross_dn := array.get(y,0) - mae

alertcondition(ta.crossover(src,cross_up),'Down','Down')
alertcondition(ta.crossunder(src,cross_dn),'Up','Up')

//----
var tb = table.new(position.top_right, 1, 1
  , bgcolor = #35202b)

if barstate.isfirst and not disclaimer
    table.cell(tb, 0, 0, 'Nadaraya-Watson Envelope [LUX] Repaints'
      , text_size = size.small
      , text_color = #cc2f3c)



//

`length1 = input.float(500,'Window Size',maxval=500,minval=0)
h1     = input.float(8.,'Bandwidth')
mult1   = input.float(3.) 
src1    = input.source(close,'Source')


up_col1 = input.color(#39ff14,'Colors',inline='col1')
dn_col1 = input.color(#ff1100,'',inline='col1')
disclaimer1 = input(false, 'Hide Disclaimer')
//----
n1 = bar_index
var k1 = 2
var upper1 = array.new_line(1)
var lower1 = array.new_line(1) 

lset1(l1,x11,y11,x21,y21,col1)=>
    line.set_xy1(l1,x11,y11)
    line.set_xy2(l1,x21,y21)`your text`
    line.set_color(l1,col1)
    line.set_width(l1,2)

if barstate.isfirst
    for i1 = 0 to length1/k1-1
        array.push(upper1,line.new(na,na,na,na))
        array.push(lower1,line.new(na,na,na,na))
//----
line up1 = na
line dn1 = na
//----
cross_up1 = 0.
cross_dn1 = 0.
if barstate.islast
    y1 = array.new_float(0)
    
    sum_e1 = 0.
    for i1 = 0 to length1-1
        sum1 = 0.
        sumw1 = 0.
        
        for j1 = 0 to length1-1
            w1 = math.exp(-(math.pow(i1-j1,2)/(h1*h1*2)))
            sum1 += src1[j1]*w1
            sumw1 += w1
        
        y21 = sum1/sumw1
        sum_e1 += math.abs(src1[i1] - y21)
        array.push(y1,y21)

    mae1 = sum_e1/length1*mult1
    
    for i1 = 1 to length1-1
        y21 = array.get(y1,i1)
        y11 = array.get(y1,i1-1)
        
        up1 := array.get(upper1,i1/k1)
        dn1 := array.get(lower1,i1/k1)
        
        lset1(up1,n1-i1+1,y11 + mae1,n1-i1,y21 + mae1,up_col1)
        lset1(dn1,n1-i1+1,y11 - mae1,n1-i1,y21 - mae1,dn_col1)
        
        if src1[i1] > y11 + mae1 and src1[i1+1] < y11 + mae1
            label.new(n1-i1,src1[i1],'▼',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_down,textcolor=dn_col,textalign=text.align_center)
        if src1[i1] < y11 - mae1 and src1[i1+1] > y11 - mae1
            label.new(n1-i1,src1[i1],'▲',color=#00000000,style=label.style_label_up,textcolor=up_col,textalign=text.align_center)
    
    cross_up1 := array.get(y1,0) + mae1
    cross_dn1 := array.get(y1,0) - mae1

alertcondition(ta.crossover(src1,cross_up1),'Down1','Down1')
alertcondition(ta.crossunder(src1,cross_dn1),'Up1','Up1')

//----
var tb1 = table.new(position.top_right, 1, 1, bgcolor = #35202b)

if barstate.isfirst and not disclaimer1
    table.cell(tb1, 0, 0, 'Nadaraya-Watson Envelope [LUX] Repaints'
      , text_size = size.small
      , text_color = #cc2f3c)
```

`
I have changed all variables, but only two lines (upper green line and lower red line) are displayed instead of 4 lines (two upper green lines and two lower red lines)

I would like to have an indicator that shows two upper green NWE lines and two lower red NWE lines

Answer (score 1):

TradingView has a limit of 500 lines so you need to change the 'Window Size' to 250 for 'length' and 'length1'.

```
length = input.float(250,'Window Size',maxval=500,minval=0)
length1 = input.float(250,'Window Size',maxval=500,minval=0)
```